# How often are NSUserDefaults synchronised?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

The documentation for `NSUserDefaults` says that the `synchronise` method is called periodically but does not mention how frequently. 10 minutes of Google searches did not reveal anything.

How frequently is the `synchronise` method called?

Comment: We don't know. That's an implementation detail which you should not rely upon. If you need to persist the changes, `- synchronize` manually.

Comment: However, if you're curious how often it is called, why not perform a method swizzling to a simple `NSLog()` and find it out yourself?

Comment: no problem, I made that an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an implementation detail which is not disclosed (probably it isn't even a constant time interval). However, you can find it out yourself by performing a method swizzling on `- [NSUserDefaults synchronize]` and changing its implementation so that it calls `NSLog()` every time it's synchronized.

Comment: It’s been 20 mins since I started the program and `synchronise` hasn’t been called yet, even after changing the values. I did the swizzling right. I am giving up now.

Comment: @duci9y Okay. Lesson learned: don't rely upon Apple, because they're cheating :) Thanks for the accept.

Comment: The automatic synchronization doesn't go through the same code path as manual synchronization (specifically, it's implemented in CFPreferences, which NSUserDefaults uses). On 10.7 and iOS, it's a roughly 15 second interval after a change, though it's not constant. On 10.8+ it's shorter due to improved synchronization performance.

Comment: (Also, AppKit/UIKit call synchronize in various places; NSApplication synchronizes when the app is terminating for example)